# Mac OS High Sierra Log Show location

Tags: macos, unix, logging, macos-high-sierra

I am currently looking for the location of the command `log show` in the macOS Terminal. I've read the man page for it and it says it gets its log files from `os_log`, `os_trace` and other logging systems. I want to find the location for each of these files: does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Application folder. Inside the Application folder go inside the utilities folder. Inside the Utilities folder is an app called console.app. Run this app and it prints out the system log to the screen. It also has options for printing different reports.

Comment: that has the system.log which i know the location for (/var/log) im trying these specific log file's location.